# postgresql remove characters start with

Tags: postgresql, replace, substring

I want to make a postgresql query which removing characters. For example, my datas are like this;

```
John Smith https://john.smith.com
Allen Paul https://allen.paul.com
```

I want to remove characters which start with https. I want to see in the final like this;

```
John Smith
Allen Paul
```

Can anybody help me. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split_part` is good for this:

```
t=# select split_part('Allen Paul https://allen.paul.com',' https://',1);
 split_part
------------
 Allen Paul
(1 row)

Time: 1.370 ms
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you soo much.